# Does the drive need to be replaced?

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

Got a warning due the `FAILED!` state from SmartCTL check.

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- NVM subsystem reliability has been degraded
```

Colleague said that's for incorrect drive monitoring and nothing bad would not.

But that doesn't look like that.

Does the drive need to be replaced?

```
SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning: 0x04
Temperature: 36 Celsius
Available Spare: 100%
Available Spare Threshold: 10%
Percentage Used: 100%
Data Units Read: 1,688,838,473 [864 TB]
Data Units Written: 1,293,261,847 [662 TB]
Host Read Commands: 5,457,149,587
Host Write Commands: 3,494,810,022
Controller Busy Time: 62,331
Power Cycles: 30
Power On Hours: 19,491
Unsafe Shutdowns: 15
Media and Data Integrity Errors: 0
Error Information Log Entries: 96
Warning Comp. Temperature Time: 0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time: 0
Temperature Sensor 1: 36 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2: 48 Celsius
```

Does the `Percentage Used: 100%` field means that all available disk resource (the estimation guarantee of no-problem usage) is exhausted and there's a need to replace disk?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "not clear what the question is": I mean, you get, in clear writing, a "SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!" If your storage medium tells you it's not healthy, you might elect to replace it, if you value your data. But that's nothing that you need us for to tell you – you're reading the same output as us.

Comment: Mine knowledges about health state of devices are not far from human health state where if you broke your leg you wouldn't be healthful but you don't have to be buried alive (the drive is still alive) AND there're methods you're able to restore your leg.
So if there'd be state `DEAD` it will look more clearly.

Comment: My 1TB Solidigm has an endurance rating to 400TBW, your drive is showing 662TB. I'll go with @MarcusMüller, it should be replaced.

Comment: @АлексейПашнин you might want to make a comparison to animal health state, instead: horses that break their legs usually get put down. And the main question really is: what risk is are you willing to tolerate? If you're ok with waking up tomorrow to see the disk dead, then sure, don't replace it now.

Comment: @АлексейПашнин if you wait to replace your storage until it's `DEAD`, you lose data, so you would never do that, if you're actually using the SSD for data. Put down that horse, as the horse self-diagnosis tells you that this horse will not carry you much further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SMART log, `Percentage Used: 100%`, [indicates](https://www.nvmetools.com/post/nvme-health) that your NVMe drive has reached its maximum write resource, also known as `TBW`.

That doesn't mean that it's already dead or malfunctioning but there's **no** guarantee it will work any further, i.e. it may fail any time. It must be replaced if you care about your data.